# Is it permitted to modify the internal std::string buffer returned by operator[] in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there any rules in the standard that violates modifications of internal `std::string` buffer returned by `operator[]` like this:

```
void foo(char* buf)
{
  buf[1] = 's';
}

std::string str = "str";
modify_buffer(&str[0]);
```

I found the following quote in the C++11 draft about `data` and `c_str` functions:

> Requires: The program shall not alter any of the values stored in the character array.

But I don't see any about `operator[]`.

Comment: There is no `std::string` in your example.

Comment: Simply because `data()` and `c_str()` returns `const char*`

Comment: @aschepler Sorry, fixed

Comment: If you can modify the contents with `operator[]` then why do you think a pointer to the element would be any different?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> `operator[]`

`operator[]` returns a reference to the character. So if the `string` is NOT `const`, you can modify it safely.

For C++ 11, the characters are stored contiguously, so you can take `&str[0]` as the beginning of the underlying array whose size is `str.size()`. And you can modify any element between `[ &str[0], &str[0] + str.size() )`, if the `string` is NOT `const`. e.g. you can pass `&str[0]` and `str.size()` to `void func(char *arr, size_t arr_size)`: `func(&str[0], str.size())`

> `data()` and `c_str()` members

For C++11 and C++14, both `data()` and `c_str()` returns `const CharT*`, so you CANNOT modify element with the returned pointer. [However, from C++17, `data()` will return `CharT*`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data), if `string` is NOT `const`. And `data()` will be an alias to `&str[0]`.

Comment: I don't exactly know what C11++ says, but as C11++ is not the **only standard** about C++, I would not depend on consecutive array elements being stored consecutivelly.  It's common, as allocating contiguous memory is in general expensive, to store `char` elements in buckets, so don't generally expect them all to be consecutive.  I have written a `String` (beware that i don't write `string`) with same semantics as `string` but with **copy on write** specifications, and `char`s where contiguous up to some point only.

Comment: @for_stack, can you provide a reference in the spec for the claims in your paragraph that begins "For C++ 11"?  This sounds like an authoritative claim; it would be nice to be able to see where it comes from.  Thanks!

Comment: @bhaller Please check the second paragraph of [this link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)

Comment: @for_stack, thanks!  That seems to only make a statement about contiguous *storage* – your first claim.  Is there also a guarantee regarding modification through the pointer being legal?  I.e., a guarantee that std::string is not caching various attributes of the string data, or duplicating the data internally for some reason, or anything like that, such that not only reading but also writing through the pointer is legal?  I imagine in practice it generally works, but I'm wondering whether there is a hard guarantee of that, in C++11 at least.

Comment: From the link: *a pointer to s[0] can be passed to functions that expect a pointer to the first element of a CharT[] array.* Since the function can modify the input char array, you can safely modify the string through the pointer.