# How can I convert a part of byte array to std::string and avoid allocating a char array on the heap?

Tags: c++

I currently have this (pseudo) code

```
private:
    uint8_t* m_aBuf;

public:
    template <>
    auto read<std::string>() -> std::string
    {
        auto usLength = this->decode<uint16_t>();
        auto pStr = std::make_unique<char[]>(usLength);
        std::copy(this->m_aBuf, this->m_aBuf + usLength, &pStr.get()[0]);

        return std::string(pStr);
    }
```

Assuming the buffer looks like this:

```
05 00 68 65 6c 6c 6f
```

My expectation is for the specialized `read<std::string>()` to return a C++ string containing "hello". The size of the string is known during run time of the function (it's `usLength`).

(Yes I'm aware this will only work on little-endian systems and that's fine)

My intention is to avoid having the overhead of allocating the `char[]` array.

Can I do that? And how? Or is there a better solution for what I'm trying  to achieve?

Comment: You could resize the `std::string` to the required length (`std::string::resize()`). Afterwards, you can copy the data into the `std::string::data()`. AFAIK, it is safe as long as you copy the appropriate size of `char`s.

Comment: FYI: [SO: Is it permitted to modify the internal std::string buffer returned by operator\[\] in C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38876111/7478597)

Comment: @Scheff that worked by copying to `&str.data()[0]`. I'm surprised I couldn't use `str.reserve()` and i had to use `str.resize()` though but that's answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521629/stdstringss-capacity-reserve-resize-functions

Comment: `std::string::reserve()` is not the right tool for this. `std::string::resize()` grants that the internal buffer provides at least the required size (if it doesn't fail). So, the internal buffer of size must be there afterwards, which makes the little raw-overwrite-trick safe. (Even if `reserve()` would provide the memory for granted - it's still not claimed to be in use.)